# Where do I find a political map with unique colors so I can make data visualisations?

Tags: visualization

I wish to make a tool which makes Choropleth maps however I can't find any political maps with each country being a unique color, without obstruction from labels, and with a key. Does anyone know where to find this?

Comment: What do you plan next? Any specificy software you plan to use?

Comment: You updated your question to a *Choropleth map* indicating that you plan to use color to show some "aggregate summary of a geographic characteristic within spatial enumeration units". Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a world map of 252 coloured countries in `R` with `ggplot2` and `ggthemes`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)

world_map = map_data("world") %>% 
  filter(! long > 180)

countries = world_map %>% 
  distinct(region) %>% 
  rowid_to_column()

countries %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = as.factor(rowid), map_id = region)) +
  geom_map(map = world_map) +
  expand_limits(x = world_map$long, y = world_map$lat) +
  theme_map() + 
  guides(fill="none")
```

[image]

Although colours look similar, they are all different.

Source: https://www.riinu.me/2022/02/world-map-ggplot2/

**Update**: Specify a list of colors for countries.

```
library(viridis)
countries$colors <- plasma(length(countries$region))
as_tibble(countries)

# A tibble: 252 × 3
   rowid region               colors   
   <int> <chr>                <chr>    
 1     1 Aruba                #0D0887FF
 2     2 Afghanistan          #100788FF
 3     3 Angola               #130789FF
 4     4 Anguilla             #16078AFF
 5     5 Albania              #19068CFF
 6     6 Finland              #1B068DFF
 7     7 Andorra              #1D068EFF
 8     8 United Arab Emirates #20068FFF
 9     9 Argentina            #220690FF
10    10 Armenia              #240691FF
# … with 242 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows


countries %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = as.factor(colors), map_id = region, label = region)) +
  geom_map(map = world_map) +
  expand_limits(x = world_map$long, y = world_map$lat) +
  theme_map() + 
  guides(fill="none") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = countries$colors)
```

[image]

Comment: how can I get a relational table of colors and countries. There isn't an obvious pattern between the color and `rowid` (weather I use `fill = as.factor(rowid)` or `fill = rowid`).
Also I have observed that `fill = "#000000"` results in the countries being #F8766D.

Comment: You can create a specific list of colors, store it in the dataframe and use it via `scale_fill_manual`. Thus you in principle now which color is which country. But again, humans cannot distinguish 250 different colours irrespective of which you choose.